# How to generate data to be used to calculate shortest distance

Tags: java, gis, computational-geometry

Scenario is I've a big parking lot (with obstacles) and want to determine shortest path from point A to point B. 
I know that there're algorithm like Dijkstarts and A* but my question is: how can I generate the data needed to create the graph?

Thank you.

Comment: I would go with real world OSM data and if it works there it should for for any directed graph data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible solutions :

- Take a measuring ribbon, go to your parking lot and start playing, record the sizes, draw a picture of the lot and register points in a file of the different intersections (summits)
- Go to your city hall and ask for the plans
- Take photos of the parking lot and extrapolate dimensions.
- Book a helicopter and take aerial photos, use parallax.
- Get google earth, zoom in and pray

Comment: For this sample scenario the latest option is the choosen one... I completely misunderstood while reading the algorithm implementation in which format I need the data. At the end a position in space (i.e. latitude and longitude) and distance from other point is all you need to start.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to divide the parking lot into adjacent fields and generate a graph of these. Each field will be a node and edges between nodes in the graph correspond to the edge shared by the corresponding fields.